# Could not change to work directory "/" when calling FileSystemManager.resolveFile with FTP URL

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-vfs

I'm trying to put a file in a remote FTP host. This is how I usually do:

```
String ftpUri =
        "ftp://" + target.get(server).get("Username") + ":{" + target.get(server).get("Psswd") + "}@";
if (StringUtils.isBlank(target.get(server).get("Port"))) {
    ftpUri += target.get(server).get("Hostname") + target.get(server).get("RemotePath");
} else {
    ftpUri += target.get(server).get("Hostname") + ":" + target.get(server).get("Port") + target.get(server)
                                                                                                .get("RemotePath");
}

System.out.println("ftpUri = " + ftpUri);
FileSystemManager fsManager;
try {
    fsManager = VFS.getManager();
} catch (FileSystemException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get fsManager from VFS", e);
}

FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions();

FtpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setPassiveMode(opts, true);

FileObject remoteFile = fsManager.resolveFile(ftpUri, opts); // <- it breaks
```

My `ftUri` is:

```
ftp://[username]:{[hash_password]}@[hostname]:21/users/afolder/anotherfolder/afile.pdf
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not change to work directory "/".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpClientFactory.createConnection(FtpClientFactory.java:130)
    ... 19 more
```

Is it possible to set a working directory path?

My guess is that the FTP library is trying to work on the `root` directory, which I don't have any permission; however, I'm informing another path via the URI, but somehow the library insists to work in the `root` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`.resolveFile` overload that takes the `baseFile` parameter](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/commons-vfs2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/impl/DefaultFileSystemManager.html#resolveFile-org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject-java.lang.String-org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemOptions-):

```
public FileObject resolveFile(FileObject baseFile, String uri,
                              FileSystemOptions fileSystemOptions)
```

This overload is not in the [`FileSystemManager`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/commons-vfs2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/FileSystemManager.html) interface. But it's in the default implementation, the [`DefaultFileSystemManager`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/commons-vfs2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/impl/DefaultFileSystemManager.html). So you have to cast the `fsManager` to the `DefaultFileSystemManager`.

Comment: I couldn't find this method that you refer. 

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/FileSystemManager.html